# Pygame - center text in moving rect

Tags: python, text, pygame, center, rect

i'm making a drop the number game in pygame and have squares which will fall from the top of the screen to the bottom whilst having a numeric value and that number being displayed on each square. I am struggling to get the text centered on the square and it is made more difficult when each number can have 1 - 4 digits in them

```py
class sqr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colours = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255)]
        self.Xpositions = [0,125,245,365,485]
        self.OnScreen = False
        self.X = random.choice(self.Xpositions) 
        self.Y = 0
        self.colour = random.choice(self.colours)
        self.number = random.choice([20,40,80])
        self.numberFont =  pygame.font.Font("TitilliumWeb-Black.ttf", 48)

    def drawSquare(self, colour,  X, Y):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, (X, Y, 120, 120))

    def numberTextFunc(self, X, Y):
        numberText = self.numberFont.render(f"{self.number}", True, (87, 63, 63))
        screen.blit(numberText, (X , Y))

square = sqr()

gameRunning = True
while gameRunning:

    background = screen.fill((0,100,140))
    
    #draw lines for grid
    for i in range(5):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (line[i], 0 , 5, 800))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameRunning = False

    #square
    square.drawSquare(square.colour, square.X, square.Y)
    square.numberTextFunc(square.X, square.Y)
    square.OnScreen = True

    square.Y += 1

    if square.Y >= 680:
        square.Y = 680

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to get the text rectangle. [`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0). Set the center of the text rectangle by the center of the square. Use the text reectnagle to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the text. The second argument of `blit` is either a tuple (*x*, *y*) or a rectangle. With a rectangle, only the upper left corner of the rectangle is taken into account. Therefore you can pass the text rectangle directly to `blit`:

```py
class sqr:
    # [...]

    def numberTextFunc(self, X, Y):
        numberText = self.numberFont.render(f"{self.number}", True, (87, 63, 63))
        rect = pygame.Rect(X, Y, 120, 120)
        textRect = numberText.get_rect(center = rect.center)
        screen.blit(numberText, textRect)
```

---

You can simplify your code. `X` and `Y` are attributes of the object. Hence there is no need to pass the coordinates to the methods:

```py
class sqr:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colours = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255)]
        self.Xpositions = [0,125,245,365,485]
        self.OnScreen = False
        self.X = random.choice(self.Xpositions) 
        self.Y = 0
        self.colour = random.choice(self.colours)
        self.number = random.choice([20,40,80])
        self.numberFont =  pygame.font.Font("TitilliumWeb-Black.ttf", 48)

    def drawSquare(self, colour):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, (self.X, self.Y, 120, 120))

    def numberTextFunc(self):
        numberText = self.numberFont.render(f"{self.number}", True, (87, 63, 63))
        rect = pygame.Rect(self.X, self.Y, 120, 120)
        textRect = numberText.get_rect(center = rect.center)
        screen.blit(numberText, textRect)
```

```py
gameRunning = True
while gameRunning:

    background = screen.fill((0,100,140))

    #draw lines for grid
    for i in range(5):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (line[i], 0 , 5, 800))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameRunning = False

    #square
    square.drawSquare(square.colour)
    square.numberTextFunc()
    square.OnScreen = True

    square.Y += 1
    if square.Y >= 680:
        square.Y = 680

    pygame.display.update()
```